# Powerpoint 2013 - Please wait while we load pictures

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Ever since I "upgraded" to Powerpoint 2013 I have run into several annoyances. One of those is that every time I need to change a picture in a presentation, the screen below pops up first. Usually it only takes a few seconds and I can click "Work offline" to bypass it, but over time with lots of pictures to replace it gets very annoying. Is there a way to disable the automatic search of online pictures?

[image: Please wait while we load pictures]

Comment: What an atrocity this new Powerpoint is :(

Comment: I have never known this feature work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the best I came up with. Not much of a solution, but it works.

Use Autohotkey with the following script:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance off

return

;Powerpoint
#IfWinActive ahk_class PPTFrameClass 

#c::

Sleep, 200
MouseClick, right
Send, a

WinWaitActive, Insert Picture ahk_class NUIDialog,,2
{
    Send, {ENTER}
}

return

#IfWinActive
```

Run it before launching Powerpoint and close afterwards.